# How to assign elements of an array from another array using indexes in Scala/Java?

Tags: java, python, arrays, scala

I want to assign a part of an array to a part of another array in Scala. For example, I want to do the Scala or Java equivalent of the following Python code.

```
x[i:j] = y[k:l]
```

How can I do that in Scala or even Java?

Comment: Assume that not all Scala coders know python. Be more specific in your description. You may want to remove the python tag as well. This isn't a python question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `.patch` and `.slice`:

```
scala> val a = Array.range(1, 20)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)

scala> val b = Array.range(30, 50)
b: Array[Int] = Array(30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49)

scala> a.patch(5, b.slice(5, 10), 5)
res5: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
```

The parameters of [`.slice`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArraySeq.html#patch(from:Int,that:scala.collection.GenSeq[A],replaced:Int):scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[A]) are:

- the element to start from (`i` in your python exemple)
- the array to insert (`y[k:l]`, here using `.slice` to select from `k` to `l`)
- the number of element to replace in the array (unclear about what happens in your exemple when `i:j` is smaller than `k:l`, but I would guess it would be `j-i` here)

Comment: Would this be as efficient as System.arraycopy?

Comment: the first index is not  0, so the 19 is the 18th index in your first array?